# Configuring the thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, fancyhdr, thesis, report

I'm having some problems to configure the thesis. I use some template for `.cls` file from the web I tried to configure by myself and the attempt was failed.

So list of problems are:

1. Page layouts for 2 title pages are NOT equal.
2. I need to configure headers and footers (add dotted lines) AFTER table of content. Tried to use `fancyhdr` but failed. Solved by using package{tocloft}

There are codes for `.cls` and `.tex`. (Edited)

Next update: after manipulation with page layouts I conclude that problems because of `\tableofcontents`. Fancyhdr works ONLY before `\tableofcontents`. Manipulations with page layouts DOESNT effected on page with Contents. solved

Next update: still 1 problem remaining. Some conflict I find between layouts inside `\newenvironment` and outside. Here is the deal. I try to make `\newenvironment` for title page and some conflict is between `\textheight`. Before Table of Contents I have 4 pages. 2nd and 3rd pages has `\textheight` from `\newenvironment` and 1st and 4th has `\textheight` of general text.... Ideas?

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{minimovka}[2000/07/21 v1.0 final disser class]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.62in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.38in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.38in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.4in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.4in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.98in} \setlength{\textheight}{9.37in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}

\newcommand{\affiliation}[2]{\newcommand{\@affiliation}
{\fontsize{16}{19}\begin{center}\bf #1\\ \bf #2\end{center}}}
%\newcommand{\UDK}[1]{\newcommand{\@UDK}{UDK #1}}
%\newcommand{\CODESPEC}[2]{\newcommand{\@CODESPEC}{#1\,-\,#2}}
\newcommand{\Distitle}[1]{\newcommand{\@Distitle}
{\fontsize{14}{14}\begin{center}\bf #1 \end{center}}}
\newcommand{\Subdistitle}[1]{\newcommand{\@Subdistitle}
{\fontsize{12}{12}\begin{center} #1 \end{center}}}
%{\fontsize{14}{28}\begin{center}\bf #1\end{center}}}
\newcommand{\Year}[1]{\newcommand{\@Year}
{\fontsize{12}{12} \bf #1}}
\newcommand{\Disauthor}[1]{\newcommand{\@Disauthor}
{\fontsize{12}{12} \bf #1}}
\newcommand{\Studprogram}[1]{\newcommand{\@Studprogram}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Studspec}[1]{\newcommand{\@Studspec}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Chair}[1]{\newcommand{\@Chair}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Supervisor}[1]{\newcommand{\@Supervisor}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Consulter}[1]{\newcommand{\@Consulter}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\City}[1]{\newcommand{\@City}
{\fontsize{12}{12} \bf #1}}

\newenvironment{front}
{\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.61in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-0.61in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-0.21in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.88in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.8in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.4in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0.0in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.4in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.0in}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{%
    \begin{front}
    %\normalsize
    \@affiliation
    \vspace{2in}
    \@Distitle
    \vspace{1in}
    \@Subdistitle
    \vfill
    \begin{flushleft}
    \@Year\\ \@Disauthor
    \end{flushleft}

    %second page
    \newpage
    \@affiliation
    \vspace{1.5in}
    \@Distitle
    \vspace{1in}
    {\bf \@Subdistitle}
    \vspace{1in}
    {\fontsize {11}{17}
    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Studied program: & \@Studprogram\\
    Studied specialization: & \@Studspec\\
    Chair: & \@Chair\\
    Scientific supervisor: & \@Supervisor\\
    Consulter: & \@Consulter\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    }
    \vfill
    \begin{flushleft}
    \@City, \@Year\\ \@Disauthor
    \end{flushleft}
    \pagebreak
    \end{front}
}
```

And the main `tex` file looks like:

```
    \documentclass[english]{minimovka}%[draft]
%packages
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{} %rename chapter name. actually erase the word Chapter from it
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\titleformat{\chapter} %configuring font size and position of chapters IN the text
  {\fontsize{16}{16}\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section} %configuring font size and position of sections IN the text
  {\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0pt}{}

\setlength\beforetitleunit{0pt}%margin before title in the text
\setlength\aftertitleunit{12pt}%margin after title in the text
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{*2}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{*2}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]
{}%
{\contentsmargin{10pt}%
\bfseries
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\normalsize\thecontentslabel\enspace}%
\normalsize}
{\bfseries\contentsmargin{0pt}%
\large}
{\dotfill\thecontentspage}
\titlecontents{section}
[10pt]
{}%
{\contentsmargin{10pt}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\normalsize\thecontentslabel\enspace}%
\normalsize}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}%
\large}
{\dotfill\thecontentspage}




\begin{document}
%title page
\affiliation{My University}{My faculty}
\Distitle{Title}
\Subdistitle{Writing work to the PhD thesis}
\Year{2013}
\Disauthor{My name}
\Studprogram{My program}
\Studspec{4.1.3. Name of program}
\Chair{My chair}
\Supervisor{My supervisor}
\Consulter{My Consulter}
\City{My city}
%
\maketitle

\input{acknowl}
\newpage
\input{abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
dfdf
\chapter{Literature review}
sesdsd
\chapter{Data}
asdsad
\section{Data 1}
sdfsdfsdgf
\chapter*{Conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusions}
sdsd
sgfsadgfs


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` to begin with.

Comment: Removed. But russian is a selected language...

Comment: Remove also the auxiliary files (.aux, .toc, .lof and .lot); the will be recreated.

Comment: it works! The default language is English

Comment: still have 2 problems left...

Comment: Your two problems are not entirely clear to me.  Ad 1: in what way should they be equal?  margins?  something else?  Ad 2: do you mean the headers and footers for pages after (i.e., those of a 'higher' number) the Table of Contents should have a dotted line?  Does this dotted line go below the content of the header and above the content of the footer?

Comment: Next update: still 1 problem remaining. Some conflict I find between layouts inside `\newenvironment` and outside. Here is the deal. I try to make `\newenvironment` for title page and some conflict is between `\textheight`. Before Table of Contents I have 4 pages. 2nd and 3rd pages has `\textheight` from `\newenvironment` and 1st and 4th has `\textheight` of general text.... Ideas?

Comment: The `odd`, `even` and `textwidth` margins works good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Problems were sold.

1. First problem was Russian language. Solved by setting default language English and deleting files like .aux, .toc, .lof., lot, .blg
2. Second problem was page numbering (I need start page numbering from p. 6 and add dotted line to header and to footer). Solved by using `package{fancyhdr}` and 'package{ifthen}'.
3. The third problem was with configuration of ToX itself. Solved by using `package{tocloft}`
4. And the fourth problem was with page layouts of two title pages and the main text. Solved by using `package{geometry}`

So here is the code for problem 2:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\def\mypage{\ifthenelse{\value{page}<6}{}{\thepage}
}
\def\myrule{\ifthenelse{\value{page}<6}{}{\dotfill}
} \cfoot{\mypage}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\myrule}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\myrule}
```

Problem 3 code:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont\bfseries}
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{0pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{16pt}
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{0pt}
\setlength\cftafterloftitleskip{16pt}
```

And the problem 4 code:

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{width = 6in, height = 6in, left = 1.29in, top = 0.99in}
\newenvironment{front}
{%---title page layouts
\newgeometry{width = 6.5in, height = 10in, left = 0.79in, top = 0.79in}
}
{\newgeometry{width = 6in, height = 6in, left = 1.29in, top = 0.99in}}
\newcommand{\makesecondtitle}
{
\begin{front}Title pages stuff...
\end{front}
}
```

Note: all these code are implemented into .cls file